# What are the lyrics to The Children from Game of Thrones S04E10?

Tags: game-of-thrones, music

At the end of episode 10 of series 4, a beautiful choral version of the Game of Thrones theme plays. It's called "The Children" by Ramin Djawadi. I can't find the lyrics for this song anywhere though. Can anyone else?

Comment: Here you go: “Ahhhhhhhhh / Ahhhhhhhh-ahhhhhhhhh/ Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh/ Ahhhhhhh-ahhhhhhhh ahhh-ahh-ahh”

Comment: Hm, with no clear consensus I'd be very interested to hear Mr. Djawadi's official lyrics.

Comment: I think I finally found them! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Njzr16W8oFY

Comment: Related: [What are the lyrics to the Game of Thrones theme?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34605/49)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Following the horizontal rule is a lot of research I did and some possible lyrics, that now seem made up. I am leaving this in for completeness though it isn't really needed anymore. However, after having a discussion with Elio and Linda on twitter they linked David Peterson in, the language creator (Dothraki in particular), and he has said the following.

> Many people have asked about this, and I’ve responded many times: It’s gibberish. He took random lines from the show and then changed them so they were “easier” to pronounce.
>   <sub>[Twitter, @Dedalvs](https://twitter.com/Dedalvs/status/954073696871768065)</sub>

---

Ramin Djawadi has spoken about the song twice that I can find so far and both times have said that the lyrics are Valyrian inspired.

> Auren91: Hello Mr. Djawadi! Just curious here, in which language the choir sings "Mhysa" and "The Children"? Is valyrian? And where is possible to find the lyrics (and translation)?
>   rdjawadi: They are Valyrian-influenced.
>   <sub>[Reddit, I am Ramin Djawadi, composer for Game of Thrones among many other things. AMA!](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/27wqjx/i_am_ramin_djawadi_composer_for_game_of_thrones/)</sub>

> “Those lyrics are interesting,” Djawadi says, likening them to those of Season 3’s finale-closing song “Mhysa”, which plays as Daenerys is embraced by a throng of newly freed slaves. “I call it ‘Valyrian-inspired.’ It has some Valyrian-inspired lyrics, but it’s not really . . . I kind of like that it has more of a mystery to it, too. I treat [voice] as another instrument. You don’t really know what [the lyrics] exactly mean, so you know that the future is unknown.”
>   <sub>[Vanity Fair, Inside the Game of Thrones Season 6 Finale’s Stirring, Haunting Score](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2016/06/game-of-thrones-season-6-finale-composer)</sub>

I've since found out a group called Zyrah Rose have [performed the song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-CQmstrdH0I). They have also made the following post on reddit.

> Quick background: We're four singers who love film, games, and music. We've recently recorded the Assassin's Creed theme, I See Fire from The Hobbit, and now The Children from Game of Thrones. During the recording Ramin Djawadi gave us the lyrics (which are Valyrian influenced) and I think we're the first people who've had access to these so we've made them unlockable on our site (using #GOTZYRAH hashtag through Twitter)
>   <sub>[We recorded The Children and you can find out what the lyrics are for the first time](https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/comments/2t2e48/s4e10_we_recorded_the_children_and_you_can_find/)</sub>

So naturally I've tried to track down the lyrics on their site, unfortunately this now redirects to [their Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/pg/zyrahrosemusic/posts/?ref=page_internal) and the [Game of Thrones page](http://wearezyrah.com/gameofthrones) on their site has not been archived. I've reached out to the group and Ramin but have yet to hear back from either so until then it looks like we might not be able to find out what the lyrics are.

---

I've found a source online that are apparently the lyrics but I have no idea how true that is. It's English translation but I don't know if it's correct or some fan made thing. [Shazaam](https://www.shazam.com/gb/track/221127603/the-children-from-game-of-thrones) also uses these lyrics but they look to be sourced from Musixmatch anyway.

> Once upon a long time ago,
>   There was a Gypsy queen with skin like snow.
>   Fair and smooth, cold for sure,
>   Venus never had nothin' on her.
>
> My God, she was a deadly dame
>   Men traded souls just to hear her name.
>   And when they did a world of flame
>   Engulfed their hearts and the devil sang:
>
> "Oh, Oh, Oh, Oh, Oh, Oh Zyrah!"
>
> There was a time I couldn't see at all,
>   'Til I swallowed that gypsy's crystal ball.
>   Then I saw that the mirror on her wall
>   Was the only weapon that could make her fall.
>
> I took it in my hand and climbed her stairs;
>   In the dark she called out, "Who goes there?"
>   She fell in love just like the rest;
>   Now she clutches that mirror to her breast.
>   She talks in tongues while her flesh decays;
>   She hasn't left that room in days.
>   <sub>[Musixmatch, The Children From Game of Thrones](https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Zyrah/The-Children-From-Game-of-Thrones)</sub>

The other one I found appears to be a really bad fan transcribe of what they can hear in the song. I'm pretty sure it's not correct so I'll only say you can find it [here](https://elainearmentano.wordpress.com/2016/09/06/game-of-thrones-the-children-lyrics/) if you want to check it out.

Comment: Wow, this is some top notch research, and it accords with @Nan who heard  "dónde está el poder"

Comment: @LeoKing I try my best :) I have some more leads too at the moment but they're still dry so I'll update if I ever get any further with it

Comment: @LeoKing On that note I've had a response from David Peterson so there's your official answer

Comment: Ah, so the official answer is: they're gibberish? Disappointing, but still a valid answer, so thanks for finding that out :)

Comment: “Many people have asked about this, and I’ve responded many times: It’s gibberish” — so my guess in the comments really wasn’t so bad.

Answer (score 21):

Well, I found [this Reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/27wqjx/i_am_ramin_djawadi_composer_for_game_of_thrones/) in which Mr. Djawadi answers (kind of) a similar question:

> **Auren91 :** *Hello Mr. Djawadi! Just curious here, in which language the choir
>   sings "Mhysa" and "The Children"? Is valyrian? And where is possible
>   to find the lyrics (and translation)?*
>
> **rdjawadi :** ***They are Valyrian-influenced.***

Since the composer did not provide a link to the lyrics, he either does not want them public or, more likely, they're not real lyrics.

The evasive answer suggests to me that the lyrics are most likely nonsensical words tailored to the rhythm of the song and made to sound Valyrian.

Answer (score 6):

I can hear "Donde esta el poder / donde esta el or?" (Where is the power, where is the gold).

But (I am a native Italian speaker) I can also hear "Dove sta il poter / dove sta l'or," which would be consistent with the time-honored tradition of using Italian lyrics in operatic arias (Final Fantasy's Sephirot anyone?)--every composer's dream. :)

Comment: And Latin, too.

Answer (score 1):

i speak Spanish natively and i have identified some spanish words which say "where is the power, where is the gold, where is the power, where is it"